# Android: tabactivity - content of all tabs gets overlapped at first

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, tabactivity

I was testing TabActivity with a list in each tab.

While running the app, the contents of the tabs gets overlapped like this. 
[image]

After i click on the tabs the overlapping gets cleared.
Here is my code :

testtabs.xml layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </ListView>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </ListView>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

And Test Activity

```
public class TabbedActivity extends TabActivity {

    private static final String LIST1_TAB_TAG = "List1";
    private static final String LIST2_TAB_TAG = "List2";
    private ListView listView1;
    private ListView listView2;
    private TabHost tabHost;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.testtabs);
        tabHost = getTabHost();

        // setup list view 1
        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        // create some dummy strings to add to the list
        List<String> list1Strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        list1Strings.add("List 11");
        list1Strings.add("List 12");
        list1Strings.add("List 13");
        list1Strings.add("List 14");
        listView1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list1Strings));

        // setup list view 2
        listView2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list2);
        List<String> list2Strings = new ArrayList<String>();
        list2Strings.add("Test2 List 21");
        list2Strings.add("Testing 22");
        list2Strings.add("More test 23");
        list2Strings.add("Test Again 24");

        listView2.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list2Strings));

        // add views to tab host
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(LIST1_TAB_TAG).setIndicator(LIST1_TAB_TAG).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
                return listView1;
            }
        }));
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(LIST2_TAB_TAG).setIndicator(LIST2_TAB_TAG).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
            public View createTabContent(String arg0) {
                return listView2;
            }
        }));
        tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove both ListView from xml layout and just create them in java code.

e.g. listView1 = new ListView(this);

Everything will be Ok.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution I found is to add the following tag to both the listviews in the layout XML file:

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are taking two ListView's in a FrameLayout that is the reason for your over-lapping.

If you want that you should have one ListView below the other keep the ListView's inside the LinearLayout like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

             <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </ListView>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1">
            </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: no. i want one listview to appear in each tab. such as list1 in tab1, list2 in tab2. I tried  your layout . It displays two lists at first(on first tab). And when i click on tabs- there will be single list on each tab.

Comment: @Lalit: Really? The tutorial did not seem relevant to the problem at all !!